# Tkinter FileMenu....not working (no error code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using the following code but cant seem to get a help-menu in the actual window.

Can you see anything in terms of menu when you run the code ? I have tried numerous tkinter templates but nothing as of yet has been successful and it's really perplexing as it must be a problem on my end but I don't know what it is ! My IDE is pycharm and I am not getting any error code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

ws = Tk()
ws.title("Python Guides")
ws.geometry("300x250")


def about():
    messagebox.showinfo('PythonGuides', 'Python Guides aims at providing best practical tutorials')


menubar = Menu(ws, background='#ff8000', foreground='black', activebackground='white', activeforeground='black')
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=1, background='#ffcc99', foreground='black')
file.add_command(label="New")
file.add_command(label="Open")
file.add_command(label="Save")
file.add_command(label="Save as")
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label="Exit", command=ws.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
edit.add_command(label="Undo")
edit.add_separator()
edit.add_command(label="Cut")
edit.add_command(label="Copy")
edit.add_command(label="Paste")
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)

help = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
help.add_command(label="About", command=about)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)

ws.config(menu=menubar)
ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.  It's not clear from your question whether the problem is just the Help menu not appearing, or none of the menus appearing - more details on what exactly goes wrong for you, please.

Comment: Yeah that is kind of my problem. There isn''t a log I can export as there are no errors popping up but thuis far no templates for help menus or customisations to add them to my tkinter projects has worked. Wanted to know if anyone had the same issue or had troubleshooted a similar thing.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Without the slightest hint of what the actual problem is, how are you expecting anybody to be able to help?  (Add a screenshot of the problem, if you're unable to describe it in words.)